# PrimeFaces Dialog can't hide

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee-6

Hello I have the following codeblock

```
<h:commandLink style="padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px; float:right;" onclick="pleaseWait.show()" action="#{bean.export()}">
                <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/html.png" alt="to html" />  
</h:commandLink>
```

I am trying to close the pleaseWait dialog after action finished.
Any help?

Comment: You may try the [`p:commandLink`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandLink.xhtml?jfwid=9dfa9) which is `h:commandLink` with ajax and use the [`oncomplete`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/commandLink.html) attribute to close the dialog `<p:commandLink onclick="pleaseWait.show()" action="#{bean.export()}" oncomplete="pleaseWait.hide()">`

Comment: yes I tried but the action bean.export not working proper. The show/ hide works with that way but the xls file is not downloading.